# How to compress very large response string approx 100MB as response in Android Async Task

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a server which sends 100 MB of response as string. I am trying to figure out how can i compress that response in Async Task. Response is in XML format. Please suggest some library for this.

Comment: 100 MB seriously ?,Try GSON and use skipValue() that avoids allocating objects that you aren't going to use.

Comment: Sunil thanks for your reply. can you post me any reference link for this.

Comment: GSON is serialization i need compression something like GZIP .

Comment: i think you mean decompress, as data should be compressed on server, and decompressed on client, you can enable compression for text responses on server level so all string responses will be gzipped. on asynctask you have to decompress and parse

Comment: Vazan is right: you need *decompress*, not *compress*

Comment: actually i need to do both the thing which is compress for sending and decompress for recieving'

Comment: if your request is small (and in 95% it is) you dont need to compress it

Comment: nope my request will contain all app data which is huge

Comment: so you need `GZIPOutputStream` / `GZIPInputStream`

Comment: this is exactly what i want. can you please suggest a Async task library having these feature inbuild

Comment: see retrofit / OkHttp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

package java.util.zip;

```
/**
 * This class compresses data using the <i>DEFLATE</i> algorithm (see <a
 * href="http://www.gzip.org/algorithm.txt">specification</a>).    
 **/
public class Deflater { }
```

example

```
 import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.zip.DataFormatException;
 import java.util.zip.Deflater;
 import java.util.zip.Inflater;    

public static byte[] compress(byte[] data) throws IOException {
    Deflater deflater = new Deflater();
    deflater.setInput(data);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);
    deflater.finish();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    while (!deflater.finished()) {
        int count = deflater.deflate(buffer); // returns the generated code... index
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }
    outputStream.close();
    byte[] output = outputStream.toByteArray();
    LOG.debug("Original: " + data.length / 1024 + " Kb");
    LOG.debug("Compressed: " + output.length / 1024 + " Kb");
    return output;
}

public static byte[] decompress(byte[] data) throws IOException, DataFormatException {
    Inflater inflater = new Inflater();
    inflater.setInput(data);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    while (!inflater.finished()) {
        int count = inflater.inflate(buffer);
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }
    outputStream.close();
    byte[] output = outputStream.toByteArray();
    LOG.debug("Original: " + data.length);
    LOG.debug("Compressed: " + output.length);
    return output;
}
```